# Dissolving faces on objects with holes?

Tags: modeling

I'm having an issue with dissolving the faces on an object with holes in it - I've read elsewhere that this can be an issue.

I'm somewhat of a Blender novice at the moment, so I've mostly been using tutorials, but I've managed to cut holes through a wall using cylinders and the `Boolean > Difference` modifier.

[image: Disconnected faces on object]

The problem I'm having is that I am unable to dissolve some of the faces surrounding the holes. The screenshot above is of the object after I've dissolved all of the faces that I am able to, but an attempt to dissolve the others results in a the error below.

> could not create merged face.

This is causing issues when applying textures, as they appear completely distorted (I imagine as a result of the split faces).

Comment: To have fast and accurate answer, could you post your blend file? use www.pasteall.org/blend and add the link to an edit in your question.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? Trying to dissolve faces on mesh converted from svg text and find the same error...